# django objects method is not responding in views.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a django project with sqlite3 db.
Currently, I am building a page which I want to get data from db but it is not responding

this is my `models.py`

```py
from django.db import models

class BookBoardModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    content = models.TextField()
    #to be updated after the sign up page
    pub_date= models.DateTimeField('date published')
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
```

this is my `views.py`

```py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import BookBoardModel


def bookHome(request):
    books = BookBoardModel.objects
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'books': books})
```

this is my `index.html`

```html
{% for data in books %}
<h1>{{ data.title }}</h1>
{% endfor %}

it is not showing at all :(v
```

this is my url of the app

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.bookHome, name='bookHome'),
]
```

But in the web page, it only shows:

[image: this]

I checked the `.objects` are not responding.
Is there any hints?

Comment: you may need to call ***`.all()`*** method. ie, `books = BookBoardModel.objects.all()`

Comment: Still even if I add .all() method, the things still don't show.

Comment: what is the result of `print(BookBoardModel.objects.all())` ?

Comment: aaa it is not showing at all

Comment: I tried to edit the code like print(BookBoardModel.objects.all()) in views.py and also return HttpResponse(BookBoardModel.objects().all)) but I is not giving me anything rn

Comment: maybe it is the urls.py? I have updated the post, can you please check?

Comment: `BookBoardModel.objects.all()` must show your data. Go to the admin panel and check if you can see your data there.

Comment: checked, there is 2 data I have put with the admin authorization.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times. If you want to clarify your question **edit** it.

Comment: Got it, I will do it next time. Thank you so much